# Excel VBA Modify Existing Equation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to modify an existing equation in VBA. The current equation is sum(A1+A3+A5) I am skipping every other row. I have a macro to add two rows at the end of the column A so when those new rows are added i need to update that equation to sum(A1+A3+A5+A7).

Comment: im not sure what the question is

Comment: Assuming you want to modify the formula in a cell, it will be much easier if you change the formula to `=A1+A3+A5` - the SUM() is redundant.

Comment: Assuming you have `=SUM(A1,A3,A5)`, `c.Formula = left(c.formula, len(c.formula)-1) & ",A7)"`

Comment: @TimWilliams could also use `Replace(c.Formula, ")", ",A7)")`

Answer (score 2):

A better approach may be to use a different formula.

Eg, to sum all Odd rows in column `A`, use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A*ISODD(ROW(A:A)))
```

Answer (score 1):

if the formula is changed to `=A1+A3+A5` then code could be:

```
Range("B1").Formula = Range("B1").Formula & "+" & Range("A7").Address
```

or, without dollar signs,

```
Range("B1").Formula = Range("B1").Formula & "+" & Range("A7").Address(False, False)
```

**Added** in response to OPs comment. If I assume the new cell is two rows above where the formula is, which is the currently the active cell:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, ")", "," & _
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Address(False, False) & ")")
```

Adjust the value -2 as necessary.

Comment: This what i have so far

' insert 2 rows at end of project, input userdata, and color cells
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  ' Update equations
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select
  ' This is where the equation exists
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Select
    
I now need to add the cell reference of the first column inserted above. the last line of code is where that equation exists

Comment: I have one last question if i want to apply that formula to the cell next to it until the cell next to it is black then how do i wright that loop.

Comment: This question is slightly unclear. I suggest you start a new topic and include your revised code.